# Symfony project not working correctly on a virtual host

Tags: php, apache, symfony, web, virtualhost

Symfony project is not running on a remote virtual host because there is no index.php file in the project root directory. When I'm trying to open my symfony project on a localhost with

> URL "localhost/symf.com"

it only shows me project folders instead of the home controller. I know I should open my site with `Php bin/console server:start` command, but how does it work on a remote virtual host?

Perhaps I should somehow change my project's root directory? But I don't have access to remote virtual host configuration

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: `open my site with php bin/console server:start` is just for launching a development server not used in a live site

Comment: Did you also add your `symf.com` domain name to your HOSTS file?

Comment: I don't have access to the remote host configuration. I can change only my local settings. What should I do with my remote host to make the live site work?

Answer (score 2):

In virtual host you must run `prod` environment not `dev` as your localhost. So you must configure your Apache configuration to run your project. Use following link:

[Web Server Configuration for Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)

**Be careful**, in symfony 3.4 the `DocumentRoot` is equal to `project_path/web` and in symfony 4.3 is equal to `project_path/public`

You mentioned that you do not have access to your virtual host to set one by one configuration. In that case the best way is using `docker-compose`, so with running `docker-compose up -d` all the things you need to run your project will be generated automatically. But you must have enough knowledge about `docker`

**Be successful.**

Answer (score 0):

Symfony's homepage in at 'YourProject/public/index.php'.
You have to point on this file to see your home controller.

Comment: Sure, but the homepage is supposed to open after loading the domain name URL, like "symf.com"